# TNTSearch phrases with spaces giving different results

Tags: php, elasticsearch, search, full-text-search

I'm currently using an edge ngram tokenizer, so for example here is "loremipsum" and "lorem ipsum" using this:

loremipsum
Array
(

```
[0] => lor
[1] => lore
[2] => lorem
[3] => loremi
[4] => loremip
[5] => loremips
[6] => loremipsu
[7] => loremipsum
[8] => sum
[9] => psum
[10] => ipsum
[11] => mipsum
[12] => emipsum
[13] => remipsum
[14] => oremipsum
```

)

lorem ipsum
Array
(

```
[0] => lor
[1] => lore
[2] => lorem
[3] => ips
[4] => ipsu
[5] => ipsum
[6] => rem
[7] => orem
[9] => sum
[10] => psum
```

If I perform a search for "loremipsum" it gets anything with that exact phrase but ignores if it is written as "lorem ipsum", searching the other term with the space, "lorem ipsum" gets all the results as desired.

What do I need to do for words without spaces to be seen, if searching using a space?

I'm currently doing a boolean search, fuzziness is off.

Comment: Couldn't tag tntsearch as needed 1500 reputation.

Comment: Add the query you are using to search. Also add sample docs.

Comment: You could enable autocomplete/autosuggest, that way the user who enters "lorem " will get suggested results already. 

Otherwise show us your config settings